# Tags "openings" and "first-line": merge / synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tags [openings](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openings) and [first-line](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-line) seem to cover roughly the same thing. "First line" is a sub-category than "openings", but it's not like the broader tag sees so much use that it needs to be subdivided (32 questions overall).

Perhaps the two tags should be merged, or made synonyms?

Comment: Whatever we do, we should probably delete the "opening" synonym for "openings". Strict substring synonyms are not particularly useful, since the match is on substrings already to begin with.

Comment: I do agree that the two appear very similar based on the tag wiki excerpt.